# "Count Complete Tree Nodes" - How to optimize the solution?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I have written a solution for this problem:
https://leetcode.com/problems/count-complete-tree-nodes/
But I am getting TLE. How can I optimize it?

```
public class Solution 
{
    public int countNodes(TreeNode root) 
    {
        if(root==null)
            return 0;
        int left = count(root.left);
        int right = count(root.right);
        if(left<=right)
        {
            return ((int)(Math.pow(2, left)-1) + countNodes(root.right) + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            return (countNodes(root.left) + (int)(Math.pow(2, right)-1) + 1);
        }
    }

    public static int count(TreeNode root)
    {
        int ctr=0;
        while(root!=null)
        {
            ctr++;
            root = root.left;
        }
        return ctr;
    }
}
```

Tree is defined in the OJ as:

```
/**
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
```

Comment: This site is for solving errors that occur during development. Your question is more suited for [codereview.se].

Comment: In static count() method, you are counting only nodes to the left and not to the right. As part of completeness, you might be missing to count right.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I was not aware of that website. I will surely post accordingly in the future.

Comment: @a3.14_Infinity That I have done intentionally. It is mentioned in the problem statement that "all nodes in the last level are as far left as possible". So there won't be any scenario where a particular node has a right child but it doesn't have any left child. The reverse is possible though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My accepted solution:

```
public class Solution {
    public int countNodes(TreeNode root) {
        if(root == null){
            return 0;
        }
        int h = 0;
        TreeNode node = root;
        while(node != null){
            h++;
            node = node.left;
        }
        return count(h, root);
    }

    public int count(int h, TreeNode node){
        if(node == null){
            return 0;
        }
        int v = heightRight(node.left);
        if(v == h - 1){
            return  (1 << (h - 1)) + count(h - 1, node.right);
            //The left subtree is a perfect binary tree with height h - 1
            //So, we only need to look at the right subtree
        }else {
            return (1 << (h - 2)) + count(h - 1, node.left);
            //The right subtree is perfect binary tree with height h - 2
            //So, we only need to look at the left subtree
        }
    }

    public int heightRight(TreeNode node){
        if(node == null){
            return 0;
        }
        int result = 0;
        while(node != null){
            node = node.right;
            result++;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

So, we can solve this by applying similar technique as binary search.

As complete binary search tree is almost perfect binary tree, except the last level, so,

If the height of the tree is h, the height of the left subtree is h - 1 and height of the right subtree is between [h - 2, h - 1].

-> What we need to do is to find the left most node that has height is h - 2.

Comment: Yet another `log(n)*log(n)` solution but shorter than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you the way to think.

First, We define `countLevel(TreeNode tree) - return the level of the binary tree`.

And we do it in:

```
countLevel(TreeNode tree):
  if (tree.isNoChild()) 
    return 1;
  else 
    return countLevel(tree.left) + 1;
  // countLevel(tree.right) always less than or equals countLevel(tree.left) in complete binary tree
```

if we know the level is `i`,so we could know the node count is between `[2^(i-1), 2^i - 1]`.

After we try to solve the origin problem, we solve a easier problem first:

```
isNodesMoreThan(TreeNode tree, int n) - does tree have n nodes or more?
```

You should try to solve this problem, and it could be done in `log(n)`(n is the node count of input tree).

if you solved `isNodesMoreThan`, and by binary search, you could get node count of the tree in `log(n)*log(n)` which will not get TLE.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `(int)(Math.pow(2, left)-1)` and `(int)(Math.pow(2, right)-1)`  are just too slow. Just change them to

```
(1 << left) - 1
(1 << right) - 1
```

and you'll get your code accepted.